# How can I divide two parameters in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

My data set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14KVfXk3ZvMwu3Y_p8e3xXabYPAGACQhYQ3QrVPS7QtM/edit?usp=sharing)) is:

| user_email | current_step |
| --- | --- |
| user1@example.com | 1 |
| user1@example.com | 1 |
| user2@example.com | 1 |
| user3@example.com | 1 |
| user3@example.com | 0 |
| user4@example.com | 0 |

I want to take the number of instances that meet a criteria, i.e. `COUNT_DISTINCT(current_step = 1)`, and divide that result by the total number of users in my data set, i.e. `COUNT_DISTINCT(user_email)`.

For reference in case it helps, the Excel equivalent (assuming `user_email` in Column A, `current_step` in Column B):

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B,1)/COUNTA(A2:A)
```

The expected output ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14KVfXk3ZvMwu3Y_p8e3xXabYPAGACQhYQ3QrVPS7QtM/edit#gid=1355058467)) would be 4/6 = 0.67 (67%):

| user_email | current_step | COUNTIF(B2:B,1) | COUNTA(A2:A) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1@example.com | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| user1@example.com | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| user2@example.com | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| user3@example.com | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| user3@example.com | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| user4@example.com | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/761e3aaa-25a5-46da-8b43-33187bf87cd0) report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 0) Summary

Use either #1 (recreates the original formula) or #2 (provides an alternative calculation that considers unique values):

1. Based on the formula in the question: 4/6 = 67%
2. Similar to #1 with the change being that `COUNT_DISTINCT(user_email)` is used as the denominator instead of `COUNT(user_email)`) which results in 4/4 = 100%

### 1) Denominator: `COUNT(user_email)`

```
COUNT(CASE current_step
    WHEN 1 THEN current_step
    ELSE NULL
  END ) / COUNT(user_email)
```

### 2) Denominator: `COUNT_DISTINCT(user_email)`

```
COUNT(CASE current_step
    WHEN 1 THEN current_step
    ELSE NULL
  END ) / COUNT_DISTINCT(user_email)
```

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/971ad6f4-8189-4aa3-ae60-21c4d43e4129) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RK4egvSEbRurGrrZVsUc0IHz3Vhstk0f3LM3PmgtdhI/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my work around, for a custom field:

```
SUM(IF(current_step=1, 1, 0)) / COUNT(current_step)
```